Redacting part of a query string with DD_TRACE_OBFUSCATION_QUERY_STRING_REGEXP environment variable
I am looking to redact certain sensitive query strings from endpoints that are being instrumented into Datadog. I've been following this guide and I've set the DD_TRACE_OBFUSCATION_QUERY_STRING_REGEXP environment variable to my required regex string and things are getting redacted as expected in Datadog. However when my expression is matched to something like filters=["foo":"bar"] the entire string is replaced with <redacted> whereas I'd prefer if the query parameter name was kept intact, filters=[<redacted>]. Is that possible using Datadog's DD_TRACE_OBFUSCATION_QUERY_STRING_REGEXP?
Additionally it would be nice to keep the the default value of that variable so that Datadog will redact any suspected sensitive information from query strings and also follow my regex query. Is there a way to safely add to this string without fully replacing it? Or is the simple answer copy the default from here and add my regex on to it?
I have tried using non capturing groups (?:...)
"(?:filters=\[)(.*?)(?:\])|(?:filters=%5B)(.*?)(?:%5D($|&))"
Tried no groupings
"filters=\[(.*?)\]|filters=%5B(.*?)%5D($|&)"
I've also tried nested non capturing groups, specifically in the last group:
"(?:filters=\[)(.*?)(?:\])|(?:filters=%5B)(.*?)(?:%5D(?:$|&))"
And additionally wrapped on each side of the OR:
"(?:(?:filters=\[)(.*?)(?:\]))|(?:(?:filters=%5B)(.*?)(?:%5D(?:$|&)))"
But in all cases the full matched string is replaced with <redacted> instead of my expected outcome of filters=[<redacted>] or filters=%5B<redacted>%5D&

Try it like this (?<=filters=\[)[^][]*(?=\])
